# Spree 3.0.0 use S3 - image links are incorrect for both admin and front side pages

Tags: amazon-s3, spree

I have recently downloaded Spree 3.0.8 running on Amazon CLI Elastic Beanstalk.
I have encountered a problem that I can't work it out for 2 weeks.
My Spree commerce is able to upload the product image to S3 bucket using the following:

attachment_config = {

```
s3_credentials: {
    access_key_id: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    secret_access_key: "gO7XXXXXXXXXX",
    bucket: "sirac-products"
},

storage:        :s3,
s3_headers:     { "Cache-Control" => "max-age=31557600" },
s3_protocol:    "https",
bucket:         "sirac-products",
url:            "s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com",

styles: {
  mini:     "48x48>",
  small:    "100x100>",
  product:  "240x240>",
  large:    "600x600>"
},

path:           "/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
default_url:    "/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
default_style:  "product"
```

}

attachment_config.each do |key, value|
  Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][key.to_sym] = value
end

The problem is the image links aren't correct both on admin and front side.
 ( The image link uses s3.amazonaws.com instead s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com).

Would anyone help me to issue this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In your spree config file, try copying this code and modify according to you (ex: bucket name, key id and all... ) see if this works, and please make sure the region you are entering is correct. You can check that in s3 bucket as well

> *config/initializers/spree.rb*

```
#--------------------------------------------
Spree.config do |config|
  config.admin_interface_logo = "logo.png" #don copy this


  attachment_config={
  s3_credentials: {
  access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
  },
  storage:     :s3,
  s3_headers:  {"Cache-Control"=>"max-age=31557600"},
  s3_protocol: "https",
  bucket:      ENV['ENV_BUCKET_NAME'],
  s3_host_name: "s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com", #your region
  url:         "url",
  styles:      {
                 mini:   "60x76#",
                 small:  "270x340#", #totally depends how you are going to keep the styles
                 product:"670x844#",
                 large:  "700x881>"
               },

  path:        "/spree/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  default_url: "/spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  default_style: "product",
  }
  attachment_config.each do |key,value|
  Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][key.to_sym]=value
  end
end
```

This worked for me, hope will do the same for you

Comment: Thank you. It is working now. Your solution saves me a lot of time. Hopefully your answer can help other people as well.